# Multiple queries in code igniter - semicolon breaks query

Tags: php, sql, continuous-integration

I am working on a project where I need to create a pivot table with dynamic columns. To this end I am using the tutorial as described here: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/

Using that tutorial, I was able to make a proper query to make a pivot table.
When I execute it via phpMyAdmin SQL dialog, the query runs fine and the results come up as expected. The problem I ran into is that when I try to run the query through Code Igniter via $this->db->query($query), it fails at the first semicolons that mark the end of the first SQL statement in the overall query. The problem is that the statement is built up of several queries that I need to run at the same time. 
I read about transactions on CI, but could not figure how (if possible) to obtain the result of the query. 
Will greatly appreciate any advice on a proper way to run that query on CI and avoid the semicolon problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is helpful to anyone in the future, I was able to get over the multi-statement issue by placing the whole query inside a stored procedure. The procedure along with its parameters is then called via CodeIgniter.